# make: override: Command not found

Tags: make

During `make clean` I am trying to [override](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) certain variable to ensure all outputs were cleaned:

```
clean-lib:
    override ARCH=32
    rm -rf $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).so  $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).a
    override ARCH=64
    rm -rf $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).so  $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).a
```

`LIBNAME` is constructed as:

```
ARCH=64
PROJNAME=libWebSightR220
LIBNAME=$(PROJNAME)x$(ARCH)
```

User is expected to use `make lib ARCH=32` for 32 build. My code for altering `ARCH` throws:

```
make: override: Command not found
```

I also tried to update make but it's already up to date:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~/$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the make version, you are using. The command you put after the 'target: dependencies' line is executed via the shell and there simply is no Linux command named `override`. `override` is an internal `make` directive and cannot come at this position. It would work e.g. like this:

```
override ARCH=64
all:
    echo $(ARCH)
```

EDIT:
The way to achieve what you want (at least with GNU make) is the following

```
all:
    $(eval override ARCH=32)
    echo $(ARCH)
    $(eval override ARCH=64)
    echo $(ARCH)
```

BTW: this way both `make ARCH=45` and `ARCH=45 make` would output "32\n64", without the `override` the former would output "45\n45" and only the latter would print "32\n64".

Comment: Ok, understood. But could you please advise  me how to change the variable during target "runtime"? I only want to alter it during `clean`.

Comment: There is also no `make` "directive" called `override`. You may have a vendor specific feature from `gmake` in mind, please be careful when mentioning vendor specific behavior together with a standard UNIX program.

Comment: @schily Well, I would say you're partly right: there is indeed no `override` directive in any version of `make` I know of, except for GNU make. However, the point that you cannot set make variables or invoke make commands in rules applies to all versions of make IMHO, and that was what I meant when I said that it would not depend on the version of `make` that is used.

Comment: All `make` implementations that are halfway compatible to the original UNIX make from 1976 support to set make macros from the command line and all such implementations support to override existing definitions in makefiles from values imported from the the environment in case `-e` was specified.

Comment: @schily Yes, and what's the point. The `override` directive works exactly the other way round and that's certainly hasn't been in the original make from 1976.

Comment: @TomášZato I just found a way and will edit the post accordingly. (Found the idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909188/define-make-variable-at-rule-execution-time)

Comment: @ElmarZander thanks a lot, I still need it :)

Answer (score 1):

Make doesn't evaluate variable assignments in build recipe lines; they are strictly shell code.

In GNU Make, you can use a *target-specific variable assignment* to change the value of a variable temporarily over the execution of rules which update a given target. To take advantage of this, we split the rule into two:

```
.PHONY: clean-lib-32 clean-lib-64 clean-lib

clean-lib: clean-lib-32 clean-lib-64

# Target-specific assignments
clean-lib-32: ARCH := 32
clean-lib-64: ARCH := 64

clean-lib-32 clean-lib-64:
        rm -rf $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).so  $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).a
```

For this to work, `NEWLIB` has to be a delayed variable, not an immediate variable. That is to say:

```
NEWLIB = whatever$(ARCH)whateverelse

# NOT this:
NEWLIB := whatever$(ARCH)whateverelse
```

Variables created using `=` store the unexpanded text, which is expanded at the time they are substituted (kind of like macros), whereas `:=` variables store the expanded text which contains no further expansions when it is later substituted. Of course, we need `$(ARCH)` to be substituted late, so that its target-specific assignment takes effect.

Complete test case:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: clean-lib-32 clean-lib-64 clean-lib

NEWLIB = newlib/
LIBNAME = lib-$(ARCH)

clean-lib: clean-lib-32 clean-lib-64

# Target-specific assignments
clean-lib-32: ARCH := 32
clean-lib-64: ARCH := 64

clean-lib-32 clean-lib-64:
        echo rm -rf $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).so  $(NEWLIB)$(LIBNAME).a
```

We can clean the 32 bit library using its specific target:

```
$ make clean-lib-32
echo rm -rf newlib/lib-32.so  newlib/lib-32.a
rm -rf newlib/lib-32.so newlib/lib-32.a
```

Likewise with the 64 bit library

```
$ make clean-lib-64
echo rm -rf newlib/lib-64.so  newlib/lib-64.a
rm -rf newlib/lib-64.so newlib/lib-64.a
```

We can clean both using the `clean-lib` generic target:

```
$ make clean-lib
echo rm -rf newlib/lib-32.so  newlib/lib-32.a
rm -rf newlib/lib-32.so newlib/lib-32.a
echo rm -rf newlib/lib-64.so  newlib/lib-64.a
rm -rf newlib/lib-64.so newlib/lib-64.a
```